# OLEDB security exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oledb

I'm using ASP.NET 4.0 with C# for an web application. There was a part to import data from excel file. I've used Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 to do that. 
The process is-

1. Upload the file to App_Data directory
2. Retrieve data to a list
3. Delete uploaded file from App_Data

It works fine from my localhost. But when I hosted the site at Godaddy, it fails to perform data extraction.

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> Security Exception
>
> Description: The application attempted to perform an operation not
>   allowed by the security policy.  To grant this application the
>   required permission please  contact your system administrator or
>   change the application's trust level in the configuration file.
>
> Exception Details: System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the
>   permission  of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbPermission, System.Data,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.
>
> Source Error:   [No relevant source lines]
>
> Source File: App_Web_importquestion.aspx.2edad644.wy5h2tcw.0.cs
>   Line: 0
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [and so on.....]

I know for sure that the App_Data directory has the read and write permissions and I can see that it uploads the file successfully to App_Data folder.

Comment: I have a feeling you're running into trust level issues. Take a look at http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/2531/what-trust-level-can-i-use-when-running-asp-net and http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/1039/what-is-medium-trust-level-and-how-does-it-affect-my-hosting-account

Comment: Could you post your web.config file?  Obviously remove any passwords/etc. but there should be somewhere in there to set the trust level.  I believe most hosting plans default to medium trust level.

Answer (score 5):

In the `<System.Web>` section of your `web.config` file, add the following:

```
<trust level="Full" />
```

That should elevate your trust level, and you should be able to function normally after that.